# Get some content using $_POST and send it via e-mail

Tags: javascript, php, post, phpmailer

I have a Javascript calculator inside a form, that computes some simple Math formulas based on some values filled in the form and displays some results inside html tags with different IDs.

When clicking on SUBMIT button, an e-mail is sent with data that has been filled in the input fields and the computed results.

I have no problem regarding the standard form fields (input, select) but the computed values. Those values are in html tags with IDs, and I am trying to POST those IDs but I get nothing.

How can I read and send via POST to a mail function some texts and values that are modified on the fly by a javascript?

Comment: document.getElementByID().value   should work    it will provide u the value of ur targeted id

Comment: You have to set the value in an input tag of type hidden for it to go with the rest of the input elements in the form.

Comment: Hi Marius, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add the html of the form and the javascript that processes those values and sends them to the server? This will give anyone looking at your question an insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: If this not work then keep a hidden field set ur value their and send it

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options

1.Use JS for performing request. For example in jQuery you can do it like that:

```
$.post('/your-url', {some_value: $('#your-field-id').val()}, function (data) {
    // some code after submitting
});
```

2.Add some hidden fields with proper names and fill them with JS.

The thing is that when you submitting form only inputs with `name` are sent.

```
$('#hidden_field_with_name').val($('#your-id').val());
```

3.If those values are filled by JS in fields like: input/textarea or another input fields you can just add `name` property to them and then you'll get it on server side.

You can read more about submitting forms here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the id's of the elements you want, simply using getElementById you can get the content inside of it. eg:

```
var someText = document.getElementById('yourElementId').text
```

and depending on what do you want, you could use .text or .innerHTML

```
var someHtml = document.getElementById('yourElementId').innerHTML
```